# How to separate auth (using nodeJS) from react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, router

I'm trying to create a web app in which I want the authentication to be separate from the front end app.
I have written the auth in expressJS & have the frontend application in react. I'm looking for a way to use only nodeJS for auth, and redirect to the react application only after the user logs in.

Is there a possible way to create a route in express to render the React app like the following?

```
router.get('/app', (req, res) => {
    if(userLoggedIn())
        render_react_app
    else
        render_login_page
})
```

Comment: Well in my opinion you should send response from your express app and according to that response decide what to render in react.

Comment: What you are telling it to show the authentication pages using react. But I already have a authentication setup. '/login', '/signup'  will show a usual HTML page, I want react to be rendered only if the express route is '/app' and the user is logged in. How to do that?